# What is the RTF syntax for a hyperlink?

Tags: syntax, hyperlink, rtf

HTML is to `<a href="x">y</a>` as RTF is to `_______`?

Comment: For the record, on Windows machines you can open WordPad and create a document with any formatting you want in it.  Then save it.  Close it in wordpad and open it in your favorite text editor.

Unlike word, wordpad produces clean RTF.

Comment: @SethSpearman Very good point - much cleaner. Unfortunately WordPad doesn't do hyperlinks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The equivalent of the following HTML:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

for an RTF file is:

```rtf
{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com/"}{\fldrslt Google}}
```

which results in a link:

> [Google](https://www.google.com/)

but without additional style information, will appear unformatted:

> Google

Comment: RTF field syntax is covered in the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283%28v=office.10%29.aspx#rtfspec_30), and using the HYPERLINK instruction will give you a link. This [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e7969408-4ab4-4080-84f1-06620d130c31) shows a usage of the HYPERLINK instruction.

Comment: I'm getting this:

`{\field{\*\fldinst { HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com" }}{\fldrslt {http://www.google.com}}}`

Comment: Note: this does not include any hyperlink formatting (underline, coloured link).

Comment: Interestingly, it appears this is reusing (abusing?) field calculation to show different text. That is, these control words are typically used for things like showing the current time (`{\field{\*\fldinst time \\@ "h:mm AM/PM"}{\fldrslt 12:35 PM}}`). It looks like this is the de facto standard for doing this, though.

Answer (score 7):

This will show the hyperlink in the usual blue, with underline:

```
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue238;}
{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "URL"}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1Text to display}}}
```

Comment: By adding this text e.g RTFBox.Rtf = "{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue238;}{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK \"URL\"}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1Text to display}}}" an exception is thrown. Any suggestions?

Comment: @raiserle Prefix that string with '{\rtf1' and suffix with '}'

Answer (score 4):

The last article works fine. 
I even took it further to display multiple links (and replaced \par to \line tags in order to stay in the same paragraph).

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2509;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22
{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1This is a Google URL}}}\f0\fs22\line
{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1This is a Second URL}}}\f0\fs22\line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about what your trying to do, but If I open and save an rtf document, with just the http://www.google.com link in it, and view it with notepad I get this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2509;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1 http://www.google.com}}}\f0\fs22\par
\par
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's typical Word-crud though, isn't it... I'd imagine the `{\field{*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "http://www.google.com"}}{\fldrslt{http://www.google.com}}` bit is the only actually-important part.

Comment: Ya I just copied pasted out of notepad - not positive of exactly which part is the one needed - but thats most likely it.