# Creating HyperLink in Notepad(textEdit)[MFC]

Tags: mfc

I am building a textEdit application with MFC. Is there a way to create a hyperlink automatically when a user write web address? It's like when you write a web address "www.google.com" the application detects web address and create a hyperlink right away. I have searched documents that explains about this, but couldn't find it..
and i couldn't make it..
i already have made notepad but i couldn't add the function of hyperlink on the notepad.

the following sentences are functions of hyperlink.

1. Clicking the text needs to open a browser window to the location specified by the text.
2. The cursor needs to change from the standard arrow cursor to a pointing index finger when it moves over the control.
3. The text in the control needs to be underlined when the cursor moves over the control.
4. A hyperlink control needs to display text in a different color—black just won't do.
   The features that I added are:

5.A hyperlink control once visited needs to change color.

6.The hyperlink control should be accessible from the keyboard.

7.It should install some kind of hooks to allow the programmer to perform some actions when the control has the focus or when the cursor is hovering over the control.

Among the functions, What I mostly want to complete is the first one. 
If I click a Hyperlink text, it should be linked to a browser window on the Internet.

Please answer and help me. Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [CRichEditCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76a787xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control (remember to call [AfxInitRichEdit2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6hweatz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your `InitInstance`). Call [SetAutoURLDetect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa4shy4a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Done.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not enough to make it work. It will display text that resembles URL as blue underlined but it will not invoke the link.

This will have to be handled by additional code. This will set needed event mask:

```
long lMask = m_RichEditCtrl.GetEventMask();
m_RichEditCtrl.SetEventMask(lMask | ENM_LINK);

m_RichEditCtrl.SetAutoURLDetect();
```

Also reflected EN_LINK will has to be handled to follow the link. For example:

```
void CHyperLinkInEditView::OnEnLink(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    ENLINK *p_Link = reinterpret_cast<ENLINK *>(pNMHDR);
    if(p_Link && p_Link->msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        //int iRange = m_RichEditCtrl.GetTextRange(p_enLinkInfo->chrg.cpMin, p_enLinkInfo->chrg.cpMax);
        m_RichEditCtrl.SetSel(p_Link->chrg);

        CString szLinkString = m_RichEditCtrl.GetSelText ();
        ShellExecute(m_hWnd, L"Open", szLinkString, NULL, NULL, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

All of the above will solve requirement 1, 2, 3 (partially –text is underlined always), and 4.
I do not quite understand 5, 6 and 7.

Could you elaborate?