# C# VSTO appointmentItem "HTMLBody" hyperlink

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I need a function to create a hyperlink in a appointmentItem.Body. For mailItem it works fine. I need a similiar one for the appointmentItem. I didn't found any usefull hints.

```
if (ThisAddIn.mailItem != null) { 

                ThisAddIn.mailItem.HTMLBody += "<a href='"+link+"'>Click here to call.</a>";

                }else if(ThisAddIn.appointmentItem != null){

                    ThisAddIn.appointmentItem.Body += link;

                }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Body property contains only the plain text.

You need to use the RTFBody property instead. See [What is the RTF syntax for a hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850575/what-is-the-rtf-syntax-for-a-hyperlink) for the RTF markup.

Comment: That's a good idea, but how have I to use it? This is not working for me:
ThisAddIn.appointmentItem.RTFBody += "{\\field{\\*\\fldinst HYPERLINK 'Click here to call'}{\\fldrslt " + link + "}}"

Comment: The [RTFBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861303(v=office.15).aspx) property returns or sets a **Byte array** that represents the body of the Microsoft Outlook item in Rich Text Format.

Comment: i tried this, but it's also not working. Can you be more specific, please?
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                        byte[] byteArray = enc.GetBytes("{\\field{\\*\\fldinst HYPERLINK '"+link+"'}{\\fldrslt Click here to call}}");

                        Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;
                        string RTF = encoding.GetString(byteArray);

                        ThisAddIn.appointmentItem.RTFBody += RTF;