# How to insert hyperlink into RTFBODY property of Outlook Appointment?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, rtf

This is what I have so far:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.Rtf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(item.RTFBody);
rtb.Select(rtb.TextLength, 0);
rtb.SelectedRtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard {\par} {\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK ""http://www.google.com/""}{\fldrslt Click Here}}";

item.RTFBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtb.Text);
```

The code runs fine, and adds the "Click Heere" text, but there is no link attached to the text.  I think I'm close, but I don't know much about RTF formatting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading back rtb.Text (plain text), not Rtf:

```
item.RTFBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtb.Rtf);
```

Comment: Thank you!  You were right, using rtb.Rtf solved that problem.  Do you know if there is a way to use non http/s protocols in RTF hyperlinks?  The code now works fine for http://google.com, but I need it to open a link like this: h323://12345678.  When using that, it is not clickable.  Any ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: I actually just posted another question asking if it is possible, maybe someone knows of a workaround.  If only Appointments had an HTMLBody - this would be much easier.  Again, thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [What is the RTF syntax for a hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850575/what-is-the-rtf-syntax-for-a-hyperlink) thread which describes exactly the same question:

RTF field syntax is covered in the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283%28v=office.10%29.aspx#rtfspec_30), and using the HYPERLINK instruction will give you a link. This [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e7969408-4ab4-4080-84f1-06620d130c31) shows a usage of the HYPERLINK instruction.

Also I'd suggest saving the Outlook item and re-open the inspector window anew. Hope it will help.