# Internal hyperlink in RTF

Tags: hyperlink, anchor, rtf

You can create an external hyperlink in RTF documents as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850575/what-is-the-rtf-syntax-for-a-hyperlink). Is there a way to create internal hyperlinks like you can using anchors in HTML?